# Why does _getch() still wait for enter instead of directly registering the user input?

Tags: c++, c, console, getch, conio

I would like to use arrow keys user input without the user having to press enter every time after clicking the arrow. Therefore, I decided to use _getch(), which allegedly does exactly that. It is part of the conio.h library, which I imported. However, in my case,_getch() also requires the user to press enter and doesn't immediately register the user input, as it should've. How can I fix that? (I'm running on windows)

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int p = _getch();
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

For example, in the code above instead of directly printing the value of p after receiving input in the console, it still waits for enter to be pressed.

Comment: In the old DOS days I think each arrow key press resulted in two characters, for some reason I can't remember. Do you get the same issue if you use for example W,A,S,D keys instead?

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue with any other key.

Comment: step through your code with a debugger ! the symptoms you're describing ,simply cannnot happen with the code you gave.

Comment: No, `_getch()` is not line-oriented, but the output might be. In C I would test this with `printf("%d\n", p);` possibly flush the output too. And as @Lundin says, navigation and function keys return two values: if the "escape" value is given, you go back for another.

Comment: @engf-010 I can't explain why the program should wait. I overlooked that it's not a loop. The point of `_getch()` is that unlike `getchar()` it is not line-oriented (and comes from the keyboard, not `STDIN`).

Comment: @Weather Vane: Probably (likely) the debug-console message waiting for confirmation.

Comment: I was just editing that thought in... but you made it. If OP wants to get the key sequence for nav and func keys, it needs to be in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-160):

> When reading a function key or an arrow key, each function must be called twice; the first call returns 0 or 0xE0, and the second call returns the actual key code.

So a revised version of your code might look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int p = 0;
    while(p == 0 || p == 0xE0)
        p = _getch();

    std::cout << p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not answer OP's question and the code that is given is just wrong !

Comment: Hi engf-010 care to explain why?

Comment: your code sample: read the MSDN you quoted and consider your code (need I say more). About not answer to OP's question ,he thinks his code is wrong (which is) but the symptoms he's describing does NOT come from that. It's probably the DEBUG-Console message that ask for an Enter.

Comment: wrt to your code ,hint: what if _getch() returns 0xE0 ? why a loop when an if will suffice and better reflects intention (the while suggests multiple "_getch() == 0" can occur) ?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about 0xE0. I'd argue that a while loop will output the same assembly as an if statement, while being just as clear and more consise.

Comment: Assembly ? When I read someone else's code ,I don't read the assembly-output. your code is confussing. auto ch = _getch(); ch = (ch == 0 or ch == 0xE0) ? _getch() : ch;  nothing to argue about ,no ?